# Why isn't my println working?

Tags: java

The program isn't printing out the thanks (name). Instead, the line is being skipped completely, looping back to the main menu. Can someone please explain why? It should be creating a new string based on the indexes indicated and storing the result in 'firstName' then printing it out as "Thanks (name)!"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] custInfo = new String[20];

    String MANAGERID = "ABC 132";
    String userInput;
    String cust = "Customer";
    String pts = "Print to screen";
    String exit = "Exit";
    int counter = 0;
    int full = 21;
    boolean cont = true;

    while(cont) {

        System.out.println("Enter the word \"Customer\" if you are a customer or your ID if you are a manager.");
        userInput = in.nextLine();

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(exit)) {
            System.out.println("Bye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        try {
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(cust)) {
                System.out.println("Hello, please enter your name and DoB in name MM/DD/YYYY format.");
                custInfo[counter] = in.nextLine();
                String firstName=custInfo[counter].substring(0,(' '));
                System.out.println("Thanks "+firstName+"!"); 
                counter++;
            }

            if (counter==full) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, no more customers.");
            }
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `substring(0,(' '))` supposed to do?

Comment: Either remove your try/catch or print the error message it catches and I think you'll see your problem.

Comment: `String unprocessed = custInfo[counter]`
`String firstName=unprocessed.substring(0,unprocessed.indexOf(' '));`
Will likely help.

Comment: @Abhijith It is supposed to take from index 0 to the first space of the input entered (so what should be the first name). So example, Christian Sanchez. It should take from index 0 (C) to the first space and put that value into the variable firstName. Making firstName=Christian

Sorry, still very new to this so that may not be the clearest of explanations =p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is generating an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on the line below and jumping to the Exception handler code.

```
String firstName=custInfo[counter].substring(0,(' '));
```

`String.substring` is overloaded and has two definitions:

```
substring(int startIndex)
substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

In Java, a `char` data type is simply a 16-bit number behind the scenes. It is converting `' '` (space) into 32 and will error on any String that is shorter than that (presuming counter is pointing to a valid index)

Comment: Counter should be pointing to a valid index. This was very helpful though, thank you very much!

Comment: Would you be willing to provide an example of the correct code for what I am trying to do here? I am still very new to Java and am having a hard time fully understanding the implications of your answer.

Comment: Based on your the format you are expecting, it looks like split offers the functionality you are looking for. Split takes in a String and returns a String array split on whatever character or regex you provide. Below should work for what you're trying to do (provided there's no leading spaces):


String firstName=custInfo[counter].split(" ")[0];

Comment: Wow! Excellent!!! I will look further into split. Thank you very much, you've been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead `custInfo[counter].indexOf(" ")` to get the index of the space between name and DoB:

```
String firstName = custInfo[counter].substring(0, custInfo[counter].indexOf(" "));
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to comment. I did try this and was unable to get it to work. It did the same thing, ran the code but disregarded the print line.